# Trouble with @Html.ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I try to do left-side bar but all time i get error "[HttpException (0x80004005):Detected a potentially dangerous value Request.Path coming from the customer". What is wrong with that?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" />

<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="@ Url.Action("List","Person")">Aplikacja</a>
</div>


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked span3">
            <li><a href="@Html.ActionLink("Przyklad1", "Navigator")">Przyklad </a></li>

        </ul>

    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-8">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: See the "space" between `@` and `Url`... remove it.  It should be `@Url.Action(...)`

Comment: @ Url.Action is working, but @Html.ActionLink("Przyklad1"....) is not

Comment: How about copying the url from the generated html so we can have a look at what the browser is seeing.

Comment: Use `@Html.ActionLink("Przyklad1", "Navigator")` Not `<a href="@Html.ActionLink...` You dont need to put Actionlink in an anchor tag.

Answer (score 1):

`@Html.ActionLink` generates the markup for an anchor tag. You do not want to set that as the href value of another anchor tag.

When razor executes your current code, It will try to generate markup like below

```
<a href="<a href='/Navigator'>Przyklad1</a>">Przyklad</a>
```

Which is clearly invalid!

**Solution**  : Either simply use `Html.ActionLink` alone,

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Przyklad","Navigator", "YourControllerName")</li>
```

**Or**

use use `Url.Action` to set the `href` value of an anchor tag.

```
<li><a href="@Url.Action("Navigator","YourControllerName")">Przyklad </a></li>
```